# android room связь многие ко многим, добавление в избранные

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite, relation, android-room

Есть две таблицы - websites и favorites. Таблица websites хранит в себе заголовки сайтов,  и при нажатии на checkbox, который находиться в RecyclerView нужно добавить этот сайт в избранные. (Варинат сделать в этой таблице флаг, чтобы определять избранные - не подходит). Реализую это следующим образом:

WebSItes

```
@Entity
public class WebSites {

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  public int id;

  @ColumnInfo()
  public String website_head;

  public WebSites(@NonNull String website_head {
      this.website_head = website_head;
}
```

Favorites

```
  @Entity
  public class Favorites {

  @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
  private int id;

}
```

Как я понимаю, здесь связь многи ко многим. Поэтому реализую общий класс Entity:

FavoritesWithWebSites

```
@Entity(tableName = "favorites_with_websites",
    primaryKeys = { "websitesId", "favId"},
    foreignKeys = {
            @ForeignKey(entity = WebSites.class,
                        parentColumns = "id",
                        childColumns = "websitesId"),
            @ForeignKey(entity = Favorites.class,
                        parentColumns = "id",
                        childColumns = "favId")
    })
public class FavoritesWithWebSites  {

  public final int websitesId;
  public final int favId;

  public FavoritesWithWebSites(int websitesId, int favId) {
      this.websitesId = websitesId;
      this.favId = favId;
  }
}
```

Запрос реализую следующим образом в соответственном DAO:

```
   @Query("SELECT * FROM websites INNER JOIN favorites_with_websites ON " +
        "websites.id = favorites_with_websites.websitesId")
   LiveData<List<WebSites>> finGet();
```

Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как реализовать добавление в избранные и удаление с избранных при нажатии на chekbox, как реализовать добавление и удаление для FavoritesWithWebSites? Какие параметры передавать ему?

Адаптер с чекбоксом, если поможет:

```
public class MyRecViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {


private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private List<WebSites> mWebSites; // Cached copy of words
private Context context;

private WebSitesViewModel webSitesViewModel;


class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private final TextView tvHead;
    private final TextView tvDesc;
    private final ImageView ivWebImage;
    private final CheckBox chbFavorites;


    private ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvHead = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_head);
        tvDesc = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);
        ivWebImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivWebImage);
        chbFavorites = itemView.findViewById(R.id.chbFavorites);

    }

}

public List<WebSites> getmWebSites() {
    return mWebSites;
}

public MyRecViewAdapter(Context context, WebSitesViewModel webSitesViewModel) {
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
    this.webSitesViewModel = webSitesViewModel;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (mWebSites != null) {
        final WebSites current = mWebSites.get(position);


        holder.tvHead.setText(current.getWebsite_head());
        holder.tvDesc.setText(current.getWebsite_url());
        holder.chbFavorites.setChecked(current.getSelected());

        holder.chbFavorites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (holder.chbFavorites.isChecked()) {

                    //????????????????????
                }
                else {

                    //??????????????

                }
            }
        });

        Picasso.with(context).load(current.getImg_src())
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
                .into(holder.ivWebImage);


    } else {
        // Covers the case of data not being ready yet.
        holder.tvHead.setText("No Word");
        holder.tvDesc.setText("No Word");
    }
}

public void setWebSites(List<WebSites> webSites){
    mWebSites = webSites;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


// getItemCount() is called many times, and when it is first called,
// mWords has not been updated (means initially, it's null, and we can't return null).
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mWebSites != null)
        return mWebSites.size();
    else return 0;
}

public void swipe(RecyclerView recyclerView, final WebSitesViewModel webSitesViewModel, final MyRecViewAdapter adapter) {

    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public int getMovementFlags(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            return makeMovementFlags(0, RIGHT);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            if (direction == RIGHT) {

                webSitesViewModel.delete(adapter.getmWebSites().get(position));
                adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

            }
        }

    };

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}

}
```

Comment: можно узнать, почему флаг не подходит? возможно стоит решать в этом направлении, а не городить такой огород для простейшей функции. Связь вам нужна один ко многим (в одном  избанном несколько сайтов, но не в одном сайте несколько избранных). О [организации связей](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html) в Room

Comment: Еще о связях в Room, [подробнее и на русском](http://startandroid.ru/ru/courses/dagger-2/27-course/architecture-components/534-urok-10-room-zapros-iz-neskolkih-tablic-relation.html)(там целая серия уроков по Room). Вообще вам не хватает базовых знаний о организации релятивных БД, вы делаете сложные и ненужные вещи. Почитате книгу Линн Бейли "Изучаем SQL", вам самому станет легче

Comment: Дело в том, что если использовать флаг, то при выборке избранных я получу их в таком порядке, в каком они находятся в таблице. Мне же нужно их выводить в порядке добавления в избранные.

Comment: в качестве флага вы можете использовать дату добавления (в формате Unix Time) и делать выборку с сортировкой по этому столбцу. Столбцы с значением 0 не включать в выборку. Соответственно будет столбец типа INTEGER: 0 - не в избранном, число > 0 - в избранном.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую данный вариант. И все же на будущее хотелось бы узнать как реализовать мой вариант, когда понадобится. В интернете мало чего есть по добавлению и удалению данных в 3ю таблицу общую для id, только структуры таблиц найти можно. Может подскажете, где можно посмотреть?

Comment: дело в том, что в вашей задаче вообще не нужна 3-я таблица. В таблицу Favorites пишите ID сайтов, которые в избранном и все. По этому ID получаете информацию по сайту из таблицы WebSites